# Update to cookie consent modal for EEA/UK users

Tags: discussion, announcements, privacy, cookie-consent-dialog

Our sites feature a cookie consent banner to ask users for permission to store cookies on their devices. It currently looks like this:

[image: Cookie consent banner featuring three buttons: 'Accept all cookies', 'Necessary cookies only' and 'Customize settings']

In order for us to continue to serve personalized ads in the EEA (European Economic Area) and UK, we are updating the content and style of our cookie consent banner and cookie settings dialog for users in those regions, to provide a more granular and transparent consent model in accordance with the [Transparency and Consent Framework 2.2](https://iabeurope.eu/transparency-consent-framework/). These updates will need to be in effect by January 16, 2024.

The updated cookie consent banner is shown below. 
[image: Cookie consent dialog with header 'We care about your privacy', followed by additional context and three buttons: 'Accept all cookies', 'Necessary cookies only' and 'Customize settings]

Additionally, some of our Stack Exchange sites currently have customized cookie consent banners in which the button colors match the site theme. We have made the decision not to maintain the theme customization matching, as supporting it would require quite a bit of effort/maintenance. As the cookie consent banner is by-design meant to be an intermittent experience, we decided not to invest resources in maintaining that feature. However, the cookie consent banner will continue to support options for light, dark and high-contrast styles.

We’ll slowly begin rolling out this design from December 11. By mid-January, we anticipate having the design fully rolled out for users in the EEA and UK regions. Per regulatory guidelines, users in the EEA/UK must re-consent at certain intervals, so those users will see the new dialog when their consent expires or another condition forces a re-consent.

Thank you for your support as we evolve our site to remain compliant with legal requirements.

Comment: "We and our 3 partners" seems really odd since the only times you use the word "partners" in the cookie policy are: "Our third party partners", "advertising partners", "Our third party partners", "our third-party Partners" and "advertising partners".

Comment: Why is the second paragraph on the popup indented?

Comment: Since you are adding so much more text, maybe it's time for the giant crumbled moon picture to be replaced with a smaller element? On the other hand, the size of this thing is already absurd; making users scroll a little more on their phone will hardly be noticed.

Comment: Is it possible that the JS class names for the buttons can be disclosed in advance, so the user script and style community can come up with a workaround for the site theme colors issue and have it in place before it rolls out?

Comment: @ColleenV: I assume it's meant to be a crumbling cookie, not a moon :)

Comment: @V2Blast Yes, I’m aware. This particular dialog out of all the ones on SE makes me cranky even though I never see it because my browser blocks them. Sorry for the snark.

Comment: So, no changes for non-EU and non-UK users?

Comment: Correct, @RandomPerson — **correction:** Non-EU and non-UK users will experience some minor UX changes. Specifically, the SE site-specific button color customization is a global change. Sorry for the initial statement.

Comment: (*The "Necessary cookies only"* text is already ***much better*** than what I get from local web sites (both government and business). They contain a very confusing word choice that can be *interpreted* to mean something like *"choose this to block all cookies"*, implicating the web site will cease to function, and thus presumably tricking many users to accept all cookies instead.)

Answer (score 8):

An FYI to anyone using some form of ad/thing-blocking (Ex. [StevenBlack/hosts](https://github.com/StevenBlack/hosts/issues/2257)): As confirmed [in this staff comment](/posts/comments/1322821), the new dialog uses web resources from OneTrust (see cookielaw.org) [regardless of whether you are in the EU/UK](/posts/comments/1322827). If you get [an ironic error toast message](/a/363872/997587) when trying to open the new cookie dialog like "*We couldn't save your cookie preferences. Please adjust your browser settings or disable ad blocking. You can access your cookie settings at any time by clicking "Cookie Settings" in the footer.*", then your ad/thing-blocking technology might be blocking those resources or that domain, and you'll need to temporarily unblock those resources / that domain to access this new cookie dialog.

After fetching those resources, depending on how your blocking thing works, the cookie dialog may continue working after re-blocking those resources / that domain again due to client-side browser caching.

See also [What is the script being fetched from cdn.cookielaw.org when I open the cookie settings dialog?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395416/997587).