# Cookie Policy page is broken

Tags: bug, cookie-policy, cookie-consent-dialog

I seem to have a new round of cookie nag screens. I'm ok with this

I *was* wondering if anything had changed and clicked on the Cookie Policy Link, as below

[image]

I get [sent to this page](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/cookie-policy)

[image]

Could this be fixed please - since well, if your reason for cookie nag screens is legal requirements, having a broken policy page defeats the purposes of this.

Comment: This is indeed a duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396105/273494 which is already marked [tag:status-review]. The author was just a little confused about which link was broken (according to their comments).

Comment: But no only the page is broken, it appears thet accepting the cookie policy is also failling, because the cookie modal shows up on every page or navigation on the site, even when you already click on the acceptance button that hides the modal once.

Comment: @ColleenV well it's an edge case where I believe it's better to split it up even if the same root cause and one contains the other.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda They aren't two different issues - they are the same issue, but the author was confused and labelled it "Cookie Settings" instead of "Cookie Policy", then discovered that in some cases the cookie settings pop-up didn't work either. The image and the link are identical, the post was just titled incorrectly.

Comment: Honestly I am confused too and initially self dupe closed it.  . Multiple things are broken?

Comment: Yeah, some browsers block the cookie settings javascript as a tracker, and the link to the cookie policy is busted. If we wanted to split them, this one should probably be about the settings popup, not the policy. I tried to edit the first one to make it more clear what it was about (using the author's comment as a reference)

Comment: But the popup isn't my issue. It's the policy page breaking.

Comment: And that is a duplicate of the post that is already marked status-review (that I linked above)

Comment: Meh it's a mess, but to be honest? It means more attention to it and bit higher chance a developer will actually take a look. @Col

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda They are already taking a look though? I'm not sure what leaving this open will accomplish, but it does't really matter all that much to me.