# In the data request page, what does the "Do not sell my information" request type do?

Tags: support, legal, privacy

The recent ["Upcoming privacy updates: removal of the Activity data section and Google conversion pixel deprecation"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396794) communication made me realize that the [Data Request submit page](https://policies.stackoverflow.co/data-request/) includes "Do not sell my information" as an option.

[image]

I don't know when this option was added but given the recent changes illustrated in the aforementioned communication, I want to clarify what that option is actually for.

Does submitting a request of "Do not sell my information" equates to opting out of potentially having our data sold to third parties? And does the existence of said option imply that by default our data is being sold?

Comment: This is probably the California CCPA obligation to accept and respect an opt-out: its doesn't actually imply they _are_ selling our information. (Though note: the CPRA amends the CCPA obligation to also include _sharing_ personal information. This went into effect at the beginning of 2023. I'd expect the text to say something like "[Do Not Sell or Share My Personal Information](https://www.law.cornell.edu/regulations/california/11-CCR-7013)" as a result.)

Comment: This should be opt in instead of opt out, and the button should say "Yes, please sell my information"