# German localisation of policies.stackoverflow.co/data-request contains 2 paragraphs in Dutch and 1 heading in English

Tags: bug, privacy, languages, gdpr

The German localisation of https://policies.stackoverflow.co/data-request contains 2 paragraphs in Dutch and 1 heading in English:

[image]

First reported by [@Bergi](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/183280/bergi) in this comment: [Upcoming privacy updates: removal of the Activity data section and Google conversion pixel deprecation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396794/upcoming-privacy-updates-removal-of-the-activity-data-section-and-google-conver?cb=1#comment1327207_396794)

In addition, the French localization has the same English heading "Country and User Type":

[image]

Ryan M points out in comments that there is yet another issue: in addition to "Deutsch" one can scroll down in the list of supported localisations (I hadn't noticed that one could) and find "German (Germany)" which is an XOR of "Deutsch" in terms of localisation. It has those correct that the other has incorrect and vice versa:

[image]

The last issue suggests that "Deutsch" *ought* to be renamed to "Nederlands" ("Dutch" in Dutch) and properly localized for Dutch, and "German (Germany)" should be renamed "Deutsch" and properly localized for German.

Comment: "Deutsch" and "German (Germany)" are the same thing, as Germany is the default locale for German (per the Unicode CLDR, which, disclosure, I did some work on as an intern 10+ years ago). The fact that both appear in the language list (which, for those like me who did not realize, is scrollable) suggests that someone saw "Deutsch", misread it as "Dutch", had some new strings translated into the wrong language, and then _also_ translated those strings into the "missing" German language, which explains why the strings that appear in Dutch are the only translated strings in German (Germany).

Comment: Brilliant @RyanM - indeed the localisations for "Deutsch" and "German (Germany)" are XORs of each other. What's localized in one isn't in the other. I edited the question to include your finding.

Comment: @RyanM I think this also suggests that there ought to be a proper Dutch localization with selector "Nederlands"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have brought this to the attention of our team and this issue should be resolved.

Comment: I can confirm it's fixed. There's now Deutsch in German and Nederlands in Dutch as it should be.