# Cookie consent going down hill

Tags: discussion, status-review, cookies, cookie-policy, cookie-consent-dialog

SE's cookie reject seems to have just got a lot worse.
I now have to both opt-out, and then reject "legitimate interest". But that is not enough; I have to then go through all the vendors, and turn of "legitimate interest" for each vendor.

This is getting beyond a joke, and makes it almost impossible to use SE without getting tracked on other sites.

I am in a GDPR region. I was unable to reproduce this earlier, but got it on different machine. Screenshots are attached

[image: Old vs. new cookie consent dialogs, showing more options in the new one]

Comment: The one on the left is what you should be seeing, [and was only added in the last month](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395258/461068). I haven't seen the one on the right before.

Comment: This is what I see in an incognito session from a GDPR region: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w75h6.png
and https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzcIt.png and just clicking "necessary cookies only" is all that is needed. No subsequent dialogs or confirmation are needed. It really looks like some other site is pushing those dialogs on you. Maybe your ISP. Use the developer tools of the browser to inspect where those dialogs originate from.

Comment: As the dialog has dependency on https://www.cookielaw.org/  I checked their dialogs as well and those don't match your screenshots either.

Comment: On what site, exactly, are you seeing those dialogs? In other words, on what URL?

Comment: It was on travel.stackexchange.com.  I got it at home, and at work; different ISPs. My home ISP is know for not interfering with traffic. I was using Firefox on both occassions. I couldn't reproduce in an Incognito session, nor as a different user on the same PC.

Comment: What browser extensions do you have installed, if any? Any userscripts? Which version of Firefox?

Comment: @CSM Do you have less-cropped versions of these screenshots?

Comment: I have also seen these dialogs on clean Firefox with no extensions on my work computer in the last couple of days, but not on my personal computer.

Comment: The questionable cookie consent listed "BeeswaxIO Corporation" which I think is interesting. It's related to [Comcast](https://www.davispolk.com/experience/comcast-subsidiary-freewheel-acquires-beeswaxio), if it matters. I wonder if it's from a rogue ads (either external or from SE) that somehow able to show cookie consent. // cc: @user1937198

Comment: @user1937198 Are you seeing the *actual popups* that are shown in the question, or something that looks like what SPArcheon shows in [their answer to this question](/a/396343/271271). I'm asking you for clarification, because others have demonstrated confusion as to mixing up what they are seeing (which doesn't have the problem the question is complaining about) with what the question is complaining about and showing in screenshots. So far, you're the only one that's claimed they can reproduce this (and hasn't demonstrated that their claim of reproducing it is incorrect).

Comment: Looking back at this, I can't reproduce the popups on the right... wut

Comment: @Makyen I had been seeing the actual popups shown on this question. But I've also now been served the normal variant (on the left) as well. I wouldn't be surprised if it was rogue ads.

Comment: The other possibility that came to mind is an A/B test either by stackexchange or their third party provider.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda Just to add another data point, I fired up my trusty vpn client and connected to Frankfurt and in an incognito window I opened the "Cookie Settings" dialog from the link in the footer and I do see a very different dialog than before. Granted it's not the same as the OP but it does have "BeeswaxIO Corporation" as mentioned in the OP.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. I used my vpn client to proxy through Germany and I see "BeeswaxIO Corporation" in the dialog presented by clicking on "Cookie Settings"

Comment: @Cave but is it also different from SPArcheon's screenshot? They do have a point, that it might be some testing SE runs, but I'll repeat what I said before: I don't think this is coming from Stack Exchange.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda Nope it's the same as SPArcheon's screenshot. I agree that it's possible SE was doing some testing for something on the third party.

Comment: Reading the announcement linked on @F1Krazy's comment, looks like it: "*We’ll slowly begin rolling out this design from December 11. By mid-January, we anticipate having the design fully rolled out for users in the EEA and UK regions. Per regulatory guidelines, users in the EEA/UK must re-consent at certain intervals, so those users will see the new dialog when their consent expires or another condition forces a re-consent.*"

Comment: As for the inconsistent theme... "*We have made the decision not to maintain the theme customization matching, as supporting it would require quite a bit of effort/maintenance. As the cookie consent banner is by-design meant to be an intermittent experience, we decided not to invest resources in maintaining that feature.*"

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. When quoting, it's *really* helpful to provide a link to the source, so people reading your comment can go read the context within which the quote was stated. In addition, that's a quote from, presumably, somewhere on SE, so requires attribution under the CC BY-SA license.

Comment: @Makyen They did, but in their prior comment, referring to [the article F1Krazy referred to in their comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395258/) :)

Answer (score 6):

Since people continue to argue that that consent window can't be from Stack Exchange, I wanted to post this answer to provide some insight (I am not feeling at ease with replacing the question screenshots).

While I still not understand HOW the screens were made (do the pop-up render differently on some obscure browsers?) I can confirm that some screens **partially**  match.

[image]

Here you have the "Measure advertising performance" section, but there is no sub section like the one in the screenshot. Weird.

Even weirder is the mention of "BeeswaxIO Corporation" in the last screen the OP posted.

Meta Andrew T. argued that:

> The questionable cookie consent listed "BeeswaxIO Corporation" which I think is interesting. It's related to Comcast, if it matters. I wonder if it's from a rogue ads (either external or from SE) that somehow able to show cookie consent.

They assumed that "BeeswaxIO Corporation" can't be related to our site but wonder what? It is mentioned in the "vendors list" page.

[image]

So... oddly the actual info in the OP screenshots match the site, but the UI and the "granularity" of the options don't.

I am starting to wonder if the OP didn't manage to query the system right as some new configuration was applied.

Comment: Your screenshots don't show the issues which the question OP is complaining about. You've demonstrated why people are still arguing that it's not reproducible/unclear, and that you were unable to reproduce the issue. The issue reported hinges on the specifics of the UI indicated in the question. But, you've argued in comments on the question that the issue is real, even though you've demonstrated that you aren't able to reproduce it.

Comment: @Makyen It does place some bounds on how elaborate the hoax has to be, though. I'm leaning towards "inexplicable configuration error", even though I can't imagine why the box in the _corner_ would be different (that's served directly by Stack Exchange's servers). The detailed popup, I can understand being different, since it's served by a third-party and might be susceptible to a configuration problem.

Comment: @wizzwizz. If I understand correctly the popup is based on a service provided by OneTrust. And again, it is my understanding looking at their site that they offer base templates you can customize. The popup the OP posted seems like it could be a "Base" template (no site branding, generic welcome message) while the one I see is clearly customized. This gave me the  impression that the user could have somehow hit some timeframe when the box was different (maybe SE was doing some test??) or there is some regional issue I can't see. I remember people claims about the box being different for US/EU

Comment: I just inspected the element and you're right, SE uses OneTrust. This is [the cookie consent dialog and its source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWrEK.png) seen from Asia. The comments on the code show each section, but there's no code inside.